# Vehicle direction OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

This is a uni assignment so I am unable to show you large chunks of code, however the main issue I'm having is that I am trying to track which direction the car is travelling in (either towards positive x or negative x). I am working in c++. In my draw function which runs and updates every frame I have something like this

```
static double dx;
dx = vehicle->getX()-dx;
```

getX() is working fine and gets the current position of the vehicle. Any ideas on why I always get a positive answer while traveling forward, yet when I reverse dx just goes down rather than change to negative which is what I want.

Comment: This really has nothing to do with OpenGL.

Answer (score 4):

You're not applying the basic laws of mechanics correctly. From the description, you want to calculate `dx` as a speed, which is a change in position. But in your calculation:

```
dx = vehicle->getX()-dx;
```

You're subtracting `dx`, which is a speed, from the result of `getX()`, which is a position. So you're calculating the difference of two completely different quantities.

What you need to do is keep track of the previous position, and then calculate the current speed as the difference of the current position and the previous position:

```
static double oldX;
double newX = vehicle->getX();
double dx = newX - oldX;
oldX = newX;
```